# Regex - invalid property name

Tags: ruby, regex, windows

```
=~/\p{L}/
```

When I test in on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/AKFhcpjIbL) - it works with version chosen 1.9.2

But irb:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"

?> "test test".match(/\p{L}/)
SyntaxError: (irb):3: invalid character property name {L}: /\p{L}/
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Why?

Comment: The code you've posted works for me on OSX with ruby 1.9.3p385.

Comment: hmm...but my ruby version also 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works:

```
1.9.3p385 :001 > "test test".match(/\p{L}/)
 => #<MatchData "t"> 
1.9.3p385 :002 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.9.3"
```

Your problem should be the windows default encoding? Case-sensitivines? crazyness?

```
"test test".match(/\p{L}/u) 
 => #<MatchData "t"> 
"test test".match(/\p{L}/n) # same error you got 
SyntaxError: (irb):2: invalid character property name {L}: /\p{L}/
    from /home/fotanus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Windows. But what can I do?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace I'm not aware of changes of regexps by operational system - doesn't makes much sense. By environment I mean the gems you are preloading or anything like that. I would try this with a fresh gemset

Comment: may be that because I use Rails, and installed it with out-of-box installer with ruby version 1.8? Versions conflict or something like that?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Added ruby 1.8.7 output too. try "test test".match(/\p{L}/u)

Comment: Yeath, it works, thanks... but. For sure now my Rails app uses 1.8.7 And what can I do to force it use newer versions of Ruby (can't use RVM because of PC)

Comment: YOu can upgrade rails and ruby at same time when you feel like. But should give you a lot of trouble.